# Add shadow on segmented floor

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to segment a floor image with different texture but by doing so the shadow of the objects on the floor are getting removed, is there any way to add any artificial shadows back?[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cEOc.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRQIC.png)

I am trying to replace the l value but it doesn't seem to work

```
input = cv2.imread(INPUT_IMG)

input_lab = cv2.cvtColor(input , cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
input_L, input_A, input_B=cv2.split(input_lab)

# segment image
seg_img = segment_img(INPUT_IMG, PATTERN, PROMPT)

seg_lab = cv2.cvtColor(seg_img , cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
seg_L, seg_A, seg_B=cv2.split(seg_lab)


merge_L_channel = cv2.addWeighted(input_L, 1 - ALPHA, seg_L, ALPHA, 0)

merge_lab = cv2.merge([merge_L_channel, input_A, input_B])
output_img = cv2.cvtColor(merge_lab, cv2.COLOR_LAB2BGR)
```

Comment: Grab the original content of the segment you're about to replace, turn it into grayscale, normalize its brightness (or at least its brightest point), then multiply it over your replaced segment?

Answer (score 0):

You can perform brightness transfer from the original image to the new image with shadows.Convert the images from rgb to the hsv color model and you will be needed to perform some manipulations to the  the V channel, which is responsible for the brightness and this will help you retain the shadows.

```
hsv_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
h1, s1, v1 = cv2.split(hsv_image)

hsv_image = cv2.cvtColor(wall_decorated, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
h2, s2, v2 = cv2.split(hsv_image)
```